# Open Graph in posts loop page

Tags: facebook, open-graph

I have a loop where all the posts have their own like button, when i click it the facebook window appears but it does not show the right post thumbnail.
I think this is normal because in a posts loop the thumbnails are multiple so the script can not figure which one goes where - on the contrary the like button works perfectly on my single post pages.

So my question: is it possible to have the facebook like button work correctly on a loop page so that it grabs the right post thumbnail even if there are, say 10 posts in that page?

Maybe i should have multiple Open Graph metas, a set for each post in the loop, but i guess this would just cause a mess, is there something that i can do?

Comment: Had you researched if Facebook supports this in first place? Details on what they allow and how would be pre-requisite for implementing it in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible the way you're trying to get it to work. You can [specify an image for Facebook to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook) in the `<meta>` tag, but that's about it.

One thing you can try is use JavaScript to invoke the [Facebook feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). It has a `picture` parameter:

> **picture**
>   The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 50px by 50px (though minimum 200px by 200px is preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1

The Javascript Example section at the link above is pretty self-explanatory.